# Wordpress empty search submit shows all post/page results

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website that has search form. 
But when i click the submit button without writing anything inside search bar, then website gives me all the posts and pages that my website has. 
Is there any way so that when a user clicks submit button without writing anything inside search field, that user gets message saying something like 'Search Fields was empty - Search Again'.

**header.php** - this is where i'm using get_search_form(), to get the search form from another page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>



    <!-- site-header -->
    <header class="site-header">

        <div class="header-container">
            <nav class="site-nav">



                <h1 class ="head-title">Title</h1>

                    <!-- hd-search -->
                <div class="hd-search">
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- /hd-search -->

                <?php

                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary'
                );

                ?>

                <?php wp_nav_menu(  $args ); ?>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </header><!-- /site-header -->

    <div class="container">
```

**searchform.php** - this is where my search form is located

```
 <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo   home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>
```

**search.php** - this is the page that i get after i press the search button

```
<?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <h2>Search results for: <?php the_search_query(); ?></h2>

    <?php
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="post <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>has-thumbnail    <?php } ?>">

    <!-- post-thumbnail -->
    <div class="post-thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?></a>
    </div><!-- /post-thumbnail -->



    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <p class="post-info"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?> | by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a> | Posted in

        <?php

        $categories = get_the_category();
        $separator = ", ";
        $output = '';

        if ($categories) {

            foreach ($categories as $category) {

                $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>'  . $separator;

            }

            echo trim($output, $separator);

        }

        ?>

        </p>



        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>


    </article>

    <?php endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;

get_footer();

**strong text**?>
```